# React hook useState not updating the UI when using JavaScript Date object on setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, date, react-hooks

I have created a date object using React hook `useState` like this:

```
  const [selectedDate, setselectedDate] = useState(new Date());
```

I have a function that updates that object's day:

```
  const handleDayChange = (increment) => {
    let dateWillUpdate = selectedDate;
    date.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() + increment);
    setselectedDate(dateWillUpdate);
  };
```

The object is updated but the UI is not.
So I tried another way which is to assign the date object like this:

```
let dateWillUpdate = {...selectedDate};
```

But this gives me an empty object:

```
object:{}
```

I am rendering the date with this function:

```
const renderDaySelector = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.selector}>
        <View style={[styles.fieldContainer, { flex: 1 }]}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleDayChange(1)}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="chevron-up"
              color={Colors.primary}
              size={30}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={[styles.field]}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.textField}
              keyboardType="number-pad"
              value={selectedDate.getDate().toString()}
            />
          </View>
         ...
    );
  };
```

which I call in the main return of the function component:

```
return (
...

            <View style={styles.values}>{renderDaySelector()}</View>


...
)
```

How can I get the UI to update when calling the

> handleDayChange()

function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mutate your state directly. In this case you need to create a new `Date` object in order to properly update your state.

You can try using `new Date()` to create a new object as:

```
let dateWillUpdate = new Date(selectedDate)

// or you use:
let dateWillUpdate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime())
```